# Weird gap in the rightmost side in grid layout

Tags: css, css-grid

This is the photo

[The picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKNU.png)

I have this CSS code here

```
        .container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 20% 45% 20%;
            grid-column-gap: 5%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .left{
            border: 2px solid red;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .middle{
            border: 2px solid blue;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .right{
            border: 2px solid green;
            height: 300px;
        }
```

As you can see in the rightmost side of the photo, there's some weird gap there. I want it so that there will be no gap in there like in the leftmost side. How do I remove the gap?

I should also ask this here since I'm new at this CSS.

How should I better write my code.

How to also select multiple classes so I don't have to repeat the height at the 3 classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will help you to solve your problem.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 50% 20%;
  grid-column-gap: 5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col {
  height: 300px;
}
.col:nth-child(1) {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.col:nth-child(2) {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.col:nth-child(3) {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OH!!!! I see! The problem was I set the gap for 3 gaps and not 2 gaps XD. And thanks for the tips.

Comment: If you can share a screenshot of what you need, then I can look into it more.

Comment: I would like to explore it more on my own for now so I will be back when I have a question. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `space-between` for `.container` and a common `item` class for items:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 45% 20%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-column-gap: 5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.item{
  height: 300px;
}
.left {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.middle {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.right {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="left item"></div>
<div class="middle item"></div>
<div class="right item"></div>
</div>
```